# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react to render data fetched from a API. My code looks like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function(){

  return {
      lists: []
  }  
},

componentDidMount: function(){

  fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent')
  .then(function(result){
        return  result.json();
    }).then(function(jsonResult){
        this.setState({
            lists: jsonResult
        });
    }.bind(this));  
  },



render: function(){
    console.log(this.state.lists);
    return(
        <div>{this.state.lists[0].username}</div>

        );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I console.log (this.state.lists) in the render function and I got the whole data from the API, but  when I render a part of the data, I got the 'Cannot read property 'username' of undefined ' error. If I set lists: [''] in the getInitialState function and render {this.state.lists[0].username}, it works but if I change the index to 1, I got the same error. I guess it has something to do with the lifecycle functions. But I can't figure it out. The data fetched from API looks like this[image]

I've been working on this for 3 hours. Hope someone could help me out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because for initial rendering `this.state.lists` will not have any data.
`componentDidMount()` lifecycle method is called after initial rendering.

```
render: function(){
    console.log(this.state.lists);
    return(
        <div>{this.state.lists.length >0 ?this.state.lists[0].username:null}</div>

        );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work!  It was so helpful. I got to understand the component lifecycle much better!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BoHuang Welcome. I recommend you to read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `this.state.lists` will be undefined first time.
Use below code to get it bypass for the first time

This is happening because `render()` method get's called before `componentDidMount()` and your `this.state.lists` is `[]` at that time, hence `this.state.list[0]` will be `undefined` It will be going to set with the help of `this.setState()` till then `this.state.lists` will be empty

```
return(
  { this.state.lists.length && <div>this.state.lists[0].username </div> }
);
```

Comment: `this.state.lists` is not undefined. It is empty.

Comment: My bad it will be empty as he already set in the constructor()

Comment: I tried  <div>{this.state.lists.length >0 ?this.state.lists[0].username:null}</div>, and I got it to work. I guess your code is for ES6. My code is using var app = React.createClass({}). The concepts you pointed out helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the data has not been fetched before rendering.

```
    componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent')
          .then(function(result){
          return  result.json();
         }).then(function(jsonResult){
            this.setState({
               lists: jsonResult
            });
        }.bind(this));  
    }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.renderView();
}

renderView = () => {
 if (this.state.lists){
      return <div>{this.state.lists[0].username}</div>
 } else { return <div><p>loading</p></div>
}
render() {
   return (
  {this.renderView()}
)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: This practice so neat!